# NodeJS: Get user's current working directory

Tags: node.js

How would I get the directory from which the user invoked my script?  I need to be able to resolve relative paths from command line arguments, among other things.  Node provides `process.argv`, where `process.argv[0]` is the location of NodeJS, and `process.argv[1]` is the location of the script, but I don't see a way to get the place from which it was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run: `process.cwd()` to get the directory from where the script got called.